# Cloning SSD to USB but Windows fails to boot

Tags: partitioning, ssd, usb-flash-drive, clone, boot-partition

After I cloned my SSD (size:120GB) to an USB (128GB) with EaseUS Partition Master and tried to boot my **Motile M142** laptop from the USB, it gave me the same error message of ***"0xc000000e"*** I see on many of these type of questions. When I tried it on another laptop (**HP Elitebook 840 G3**) the error code was ***"0xc0000225"***

> Your PC needs to be repaired
>
> The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
>
> File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
> Error code: 0xc000000e

My question is: While I know a HDD can successfully be cloned to an internal SSD, can the SSD also be cloned to a USB, which is then bootable? Because right now, I don't see evidence that such a thing is even possible.

Comment: If you intend to boot Windows then no, not really. A mainstream Linux almost certainly would boot fine. In order to use Windows from external drives there used to be the official Windows To Go, deprecated because the performance was abysmal. Now there are 3rd party solutions from Rufus and maybe a couple more. A simple clone like you did won't work.

Comment: FWIW, I am not a moderator but a community member who can edit. I respect your edits and [rolled back my changes](https://superuser.com/posts/1828574/revisions) except for two: Quote formatting for the error message as well as removing “first” from the question are since there is only one question. Respect.